# How can i call a assembly function from another assembly file?

Tags: c, ubuntu, nasm

Actually, I'm using NASM for my scholar project. The idea is to build one static library for Math Operations.

I've been able to build separate functions in different asm files. Example:

- **add_vectorial**

  - With 3 Parameters:

    - d, size
    - v1, array of float
    - v2, array of float
    - rt, array of float that it must contain the result of operation
- **sub_vectorial**

  - With 3 Parameters:

    - d, size
    - v1, array of float
    - v2, array of float
    - rt, array of float that it must contain the result of operation

But I have an third asm file that it must call the 2 functions: **add_vectorial** and **sub_vectorial** for to do some calculus.

I've read that i must to use the call word for calling my external function. But I don't have idea how can i pass the parameter??

Example of my code:

```
extern add_vectorial

global operation:    ;for linux

operation:
            ;Initialize a stack frame
            push    ebp
            mov     ebp, esp
            ;Loading the arguments values
            mov     ebx, [ebp+8]    ; ebx='d'
            mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ; ecx='v1'
            mov     edx, [ebp+16]   ; edx='v2'
            mov     eax, [ebp+20]   ; eax = rt

            ;Initial the xmm4 registry with zero.
            xorps   xmm4, xmm4
.body:

            ;Here, How can i pass the parameters to my asm external function?
            call   add_vectorial

.done:
            ;Restore the call's stack frame pointer
            leave                   ; mov esp,ebp / pop ebp 
            ret                     ; return from function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for your support... Finally I found a one solution to my problem... I leave my solution..

```
%macro call_fun1  4
pushad             ;I put this
push %4
push %3
push %2
push %1
call sub_vectorial
add  esp, 16   ;4p*4bytes
popad             ;I put this
%endmacro
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the parameters by pushing them onto the stack before you execute the call statement, or by inserting them into registers first.

Comment: If you are pushing them into the stack, you will need to either pop them off the stack in the calling function (the way C cdecl does it) or put a number after ret, telling it how many bytes to pop off the stack (the way C stdcall does it)

Comment: Hi @cup .. thanks for you answers. I've used macros for calling my external asm files. I put one example of my code like comment. But I have a new error. I don't know if you can suggest to me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a macro for calling my external functions, passing the parameter like in C.

```
%macro call_fun1  4
push %4
push %3
push %2
push %1
call sub_vectorial
add  ebp, 16   ;4p*4bytes
%endmacro
```

Only when i integrate this code with my main asm file, give me the follow error: **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.**

For this reason i made one unit test of my function, but the function work fine.

The error only is to give when i integrate with the rest of my code.

Comment: Try **add esp,16**.  esp is the stack pointer.  ebp is the base pointer.  When you push items into the stack, esp changes, ebp remains the same.

Comment: Thanks @cup, I've corrected the error, but unfortunately i keep having the same error...

Comment: What is the return instruction on sub_vectorial?  Is it **ret** or **ret 16**?  If it is **ret 16**then it is behaving like std call and you shouldn't need to add to esp on exit.